# error when doing a phpunit or phpunit --version

Tags: php, phpunit

I get an error message when I enter phpunit in my bash shell. I am using yosemite. I manually installed phpunit and was getting the error msg below. I also done a global installation composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.7.*"

```
(master) $: phpunit

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-         imagick/imagick.so, 9): Symbol not found: _core_globals
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library   '/usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so, 9): Symbol not found: _core_globals
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/opt/php56-imagick/imagick.so in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Seems a problem related to the php installation, not phpunit. I think you can have the same problem running the command `php -m`

Comment: @Matteo - yeah I do get the same issue doing php -m. I might have to reinstall php.

Comment: @Bjorn's solution worked for me. Maybe add an official answer Bjorn?

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinstall. Just disable the extension by removing the symlink from the `conf.d` directory. Where the conf.d folder is located depends on your installation.

For example:

- Homebrew: `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d`
- Ubuntu: `/etc/php5/[sapi]/conf.d/`